# min and max funtions are not working in python with date

Tags: python

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsbMy.png)

Hi,

I am trying to find the minimum and maximum date for my data(excel) which I have uploaded to Python.
I am using the below code, it is displaying the wrong result.

```
country_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(country_df['Date'])

min(country_df['Date'])
```

Which is giving output as datetime.date(2020, 1, 2)  which is wrong as in my data the min date is 30/01/2020

Please see the attached data image.

can any one help me out this please?

Comment: datetime.date(2020, 1, 2) is January 2 2020, which is indeed smaller (earlier) than 30/01/2020 (January 30 2020).

Comment: But i dont have the data which has January 2 2020, In real my data starts with 30/01/2020  which is minimum but it displaying worng when i using the same in python min function

Comment: Sounds like you want `pd.to_datetime(country_df['Date'], dayfirst=True)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks, I have tried with this, Still not working  Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00')

Comment: I thought you just said the input was in the format `30/01/2020` (eg. `dd/MM/yyyy`)? Is the input data a mix of differently formatted timestamps?

Comment: No, The entire column is in same format like 30/01/2020. And i am using min and max on that coulmn

Comment: If you can see the attached data file i wrote normal excel function to get the min and max date it is showing the correct data but when comes to python it is not